# Find the form of $Y(t)$,$(D-2)^3(D+1)Y=3e^{2t}-te^{-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $(D-2)^3(D+1)Y=3e^{2t}-te^{-t}$
> (a) Show that $(D − 2)$ and $(D + 1)^2$
> respectively are annihilators of the right side of the equation,
> and that the combined operator $(D − 2)(D + 1)^2$ annihilates both terms on the right side of the
> equation simultaneously.
> (b) Find Y (t)

I've managed to solve (a) and I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
I think I need to use that $(D − 2)(D + 1)^2(3e^{2t}-te^{-t})\in Ker((D − 2)(D + 1)^2)$ and Y(t) will have the form of some quasi-polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The "minimal" polynomial of annihilators is $(D-2)^4(D+1)^3Y = 0$ which means the solution will be of the form

$$Y(t) = Ae^{2t}+Bte^{2t}+Ct^2e^{2t}+Dt^3e^{2t}+Ee^{-t}+Fte^{-t}+Gt^2e^{-t}$$

This means the particular solution will require you to explicitly solve for $D,F,G$

$$Y_p(t) = Dt^3e^{2t}+Fte^{-t}+Gt^2e^{-t}$$

in the original equation. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand why you multiply by (D+1) but not about (D-2) and you mean E instead of F?because we got F=-1 in the original equation

Comment: @convxy the first rule of equations, what you do to one side, you do to the other. These are the operators you have to apply to cancel out the right hand side of the original equation. And not, I don't mean $E$, the $E$ term is part of the kernel of original, unmodified equation. The particular solution is everything that is not in the kernel of the original. I don't know if $F=-1$, you'll have to solve for that yourself.